# Modifying an imported library in Go

Tags: go, libraries

## My Problem

[Elastic Beats](https://www.elastic.co/products/beats) is an open source project for log shippers written in Go. It features several log outputs, including console, Elasticsearch and Redis. I would like to add an output of my own - to AWS Kinesis.

I have cloned the repo to `~/github/beats`, and tried building it:

```
$ cd filebeat; go build main.go
```

However, it failed due to a missing library *which is a part of the project*:

```
main.go:6:2: cannot find package "github.com/elastic/beats/filebeat/cmd" in any of:
    /usr/local/go/src/github.com/elastic/beats/filebeat/cmd (from $GOROOT)
    /Users/adam/go/src/github.com/elastic/beats/filebeat/cmd (from $GOPATH)
```

A directory of the project is dependent on a package from the same repo, but instead of looking one directory up the hierarchy it looks in the `GOPATH`.

So, `go get github.com/elastic/beats/filebeat/cmd` fetched the code, and now `go build main.go` works. Changing the code in my `GOPATH` is reflected in these builds.

This leaves me with an structural inconvenience. Some of my code is at a working directory, and some of it is at my `GOPATH` and included by the code in my working directory.

I would like to have all my code in a single directory for various reasons, not the least being keeping everything under version control.

## What Have I Tried

Mostly searching for the problem. I am quite new to Go, so I might have missed the correct terminology.

## My Question

What is the right way to edit the code of an imported library in Go?

Comment: All your code should be in your GOPATH. Always. Reference: [`How to Write Go Code`](https://golang.org/doc/code.html)

Comment: As JimB says. This should be checked out into `/Users/adam/go/src/github.com/elastic/beats`. Then everything will work normally.

Comment: Thanks for the comments. I've started my problem clearly and did my homework. Why the downvote?

Comment: No need to downvote. Faced exactly the same problem, might be typical for a go newbie.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A project working copy should be checked out into `$GOPATH/src/package/import/path` - for example, this project should be checked out into `/Users/adam/go/src/github.com/elastic/beats`. With the project in the correct location, the go tooling will be able to operate on it normally; otherwise, it will not be able to resolve imports correctly. See `go help gopath` for more info.

Answer (score 7):

Previous answers to this question are obsolete when developing projects that using [Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules).

For projects that using [Go Modules](https://blog.golang.org/using-go-modules), one may use the following command to replace an imported library(eg. example.com/imported/module) with a local module(eg. ./local/module):

```
go mod edit -replace=example.com/imported/module=./local/module
```

Or by adding the following line into the `go.mod` file:

```
replace example.com/imported/module => ./local/module
```

Reference Docs: https://golang.org/doc/modules/managing-dependencies#unpublished

Answer (score 4):

One of the recommended ways to work with other's packages is:

1. Get the sources of the original package:

   ```
   go get github.com/elastic/beats
   ```

   As a result you will clone project's git repository to the folder

   ```
   $GOPATH/src/github.com/elastic/beats
   ```
2. Make some fixes, compile code, fix, compile... When you make `go install` package will be compiled and installed to your system. When you need merge updates from original repository you can `git pull` them.

**Everything is OK. What's next? How to share your work with others?**

3. Fork project on github, suppose it will be `github.com/username/beats`
4. Add this fork as another remote `mycopy` (or any other name you like) to your local repository

   ```
   git remote add mycopy git://github.com/username/beats.git
   ```
5. When all is done you can push updated sources to your repo on github

   ```
   git push mycopy
   ```

   and then open a pull-request to original sources. This way you can share your work with others. And keep your changes in sync with mainstream.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "compile code, fix compile, go install"?  I made changes but go build & go install did nothing