# I need consume my library golang from local to test changes first

Tags: go

I have changes locally in my library golang, that changes I have to test first before push to github repository, my idea is test from another service module and call the library to consume the methods. Can I achieve this ?

Comment: You are using go modules?

Comment: You can place this peckage inside your service module and test it.

Comment: its a tricky right ?, I thought in a solution like gradle install, but im newbee in golang. thanks @HamzaAnis . I'm trying

Comment: You can refer to my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52125437/go-module-init-without-vcs-git-fails-with-cannot-determine-module-path/52127799#52127799) and use the package without publishing it on GitHub.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The responses was confuse, for clarify that, I would prefer documenting better my solution:

In the file go.mod, I have to use my local development instead of repository github.com/../../..

We have one step, simply, write replace <github.com/repository> => myLocalFolder

Example:

```
//go.mod
require (
    //this is a repository that I want change
    github.com/example/my-reposiory v1.2.0
    
)
```

//Here, writing replace, Im achieve use the local code instead of repository code

```
replace github.com/avaldigitallabs/adl-habilitadora-lib-go-shared-kernel => /Users/<my_user>/Documents/Projects/my_local_folder
```

//go.mod complete example:

```
module my-module

go 1.14

require (
    github.com/example/my-reposiory v1.2.0
)

replace github.com/example/my-reposiory => /Users/<my_user>/Documents/Projects/my_local_folder
```

Comment: `replace` the github module by local module works for me. [modifying-an-imported-library-in-go](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47516188/modifying-an-imported-library-in-go)

Answer (score -1):

> Can I achieve this ?

Yes of course. Just do it. A `replace` directive in go.mod might help you.

Comment: Interesting, let me try first, Im reading the documentation.